# Password uniqueness when user edits password using devise in rails

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise gem for my user accounts. 
When updating the password, the user should not enter the same old password.
Is there any way using devise authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by over riding your model's `update_with_password` method.

See: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L61

So, something like...

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base

  # TODO - Handle blank/missing fields, set error message, etc.
  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    return false if params[:password] == params[:current_password]
    super
  end

end
```